# Oracle Retrieve correct records using bind variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following query where it retrieves records as per the join and bind variable input

```
select distinct G.GAME_ID,  G.GAME_TYPE_ID, G.GAME_DATE,  CY.DISPLAY_NAME AS NAME

            FROM FOOTBALL.FY_CALENDAR_MV CL
                 JOIN FIFA_OWNR.GAME G
                    ON TO_DATE ( TO_CHAR (G.GAME_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY') = CL.CAL_DT

                 JOIN FIFA_OWNR.ICE_MANAGER IM
                    ON G.CREATED_BY = IM.USER_ID
                 JOIN FIFA_OWNR.MANAGER_HIST MH
                    ON     MH.MANAGER_ID = IM.MANAGER_ID
                 JOIN FIFA_OWNR.MV_COUNTRY_LOCATION_LKUP CY
                    ON CY.LOCATION_CODE = MH.OFFICE_LOCATION_CODE
                 and CY.DISPLAY_NAME in (:LOCAL_OFFICE)
```

Upon providing the value of bind variable it retrieves the records as per the bind value

**Actual Output / ERROR / ISSUE**

```
ENTER BINDS     ----    LOCAL_OFFICE    ----    Value = ASIA

GAME_ID GAME_TYPE_ID    GAME_DATE           NAME
1362    Friendly2       21-JAN-20           ASIA    
1540    Friendly2       21-JAN-20           ASIA    
1680    Friendly2       24-JAN-20           ASIA    
1607    Competition3    25-JAN-20           ASIA



ENTER BINDS     ----    LOCAL_OFFICE    ----    Value = EUROPE

GAME_ID GAME_TYPE_ID    GAME_DATE           NAME
NO Records show up
```

**Expected / Correct Output**

```
ENTER BINDS     ----    LOCAL_OFFICE    ----    Value = ASIA

GAME_ID GAME_TYPE_ID    GAME_DATE           NAME
1680    Friendly2       24-JAN-20           ASIA    
1607    Competition3    25-JAN-20           ASIA    

ENTER BINDS     ----    LOCAL_OFFICE    ----    Value = EUROPE

GAME_ID GAME_TYPE_ID    GAME_DATE           NAME
1362    Friendly2       21-JAN-20           EUROPE  
1540    Friendly2       21-JAN-20           EUROPE
```

I have created a sample sql fiddle

Bound variables for the fiddle

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=735a8ad9dd4ca4c9b145ca0b41ec886c

and CY.DISPLAY_NAME ='ASIA';
  and CY.DISPLAY_NAME ='EUROPE';

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ea07dac8b7f35a5b5c3005531f7a5190

TABLE   FIFA_OWNR.GAME;

```
  GAME_ID,              GAME_DATE,               GAME_TYPE_ID,      CATEGORY_ID, ,COUNTRY_CODE,    CREATED_BY
  1362,         to_date('21-JAN-20','DD-MON-RR'),Friendly2,             9,         '08',          'beckham'
  1540                  21-JAN-20                Friendly2              9           08             beckham
  1680                  24-JAN-20                Friendly2              9           07             beckham
  1607                  25-JAN-20                Competition3           17          07             beckham
  1687                  25-JAN-20                Competition3           17          04             beckham
```

In the lookup table the location code 6 represents ASIA location code 8 EUROPE

TABLE   FIFA_OWNR.MV_COUNTRY_LOCATION_LKUP

```
LOCATION_CODE,      DISPLAY_NAME                    LOCATION_ABBR
1                   AMERICA                         01/02/03
4                   AFRICA                          04
5                   AUS PACIFIC                     05/06
6                   ASIA                            07  
8                   EUROPE                          08
```

TABLE   FIFA_OWNR.MANAGER_HIST

```
MANAGER_ID,DEFAULT_COUNTRY_CODE,OFFICE_LOCATION_CODE
242         01                      1
238         08                      8
239         08                      8
240         06                      5
243         7B                      6
```

TABLE   FIFA_OWNR.ICE_MANAGER

```
USER_ID          MANAGER_ID
beckham             242
beckham             238
beckham             239
beckham             240
beckham             243
```

TABLE   FOOTBALL.FY_CALENDAR_MV;

```
CAL_DT      CAL_MTH             YEAR
21-JAN-20   1                   2020
21-JAN-20   1                   2020
24-JAN-20   1                   2020
25-JAN-20   1                   2020
```

*Issue is it is unable to retrieve the records as per the bind values*

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the join in your query:

```
select distinct G.GAME_ID,  G.GAME_TYPE_ID, G.GAME_DATE,  CY.DISPLAY_NAME AS NAME
            FROM FY_CALENDAR_MV CL
                 JOIN GAME G
                    ON G.GAME_DATE = CL.CAL_DT
                 JOIN ICE_MANAGER IM
                    ON G.CREATED_BY = IM.USER_ID
                 JOIN MANAGER_HIST MH
                    ON     MH.MANAGER_ID = IM.MANAGER_ID
                 JOIN MV_COUNTRY_LOCATION_LKUP CY
                    ON CY.LOCATION_ABBR = G.COUNTRY_CODE -- This join is changed
                 and CY.DISPLAY_NAME ='ASIA';
```

see [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e832ce4acac63f412e14e28ebfcee93d) for correct output for ASIA and EUROPE

Comment: Thank you for the input, If a new record is introduced for TABLE FIFA_OWNR.GAME;
like   GAME_ID, 2040   GAME_DATE, 26-JAN-20     GAME_TYPE_ID, Friendly2 CATEGORY_ID, 9 ,COUNTRY_CODE, 02    CREATED_BY  beckham
  
  and searches for the local office AMERICA It fails    https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6e6224ee84d9a70d66a435bb7f89012a         Is there a work around for this?